# Realm File not found ERROR Android

Tags: android, realm

All these time, I was thinking that realm file is created when RealmConfiguration is created. But today when I observed, the realm file is created when the data is written to it using Realm.getDefaultInstance(). We have login / logout function in our App. I have realm configuration defined in Application class.

```
val realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(RealmMigrationClass())
                .build()

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)
```

During login, I fetch all the details from the user and user related information from backend and store it in realm.

During logout, I delete all the app related data (i.e) I delete the files from getFilesDir() as well. So during logout, the realm file gets deleted.

During relogin, Login activity is called (The realmConfiguration in MainApp is undisturbed) and again user details are fetched and saved in realm.

We have social login integrated into app. For Google SignIn, We could not sign out anywhere other than the Login Activity where mGoogleApiClient is initialized. So, during logout we did not logout the google user, we do logout the user during the next signin request.

```
googleLogin.onClick {

            if(mGoogleApiClient?.isConnected ?:false){
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient)
                val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN)
            }else{
                val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN)
            }
        }
```

We do support our custom login, logout. We do have twitter login / Logout, we do have facebook login/logout in addition to google. But just google sign in alone causes issue during relogin (i.e User logs in the app successfully using any mode including google signin. First time works perfectly fine. but if the user signs out and tries relogin with google, it fails. but relogin with other modes custom, facebook and twitter works perfectly fine). After login, while trying to write user details to realm, it complains that the realm file does not exist and shows unexpected error occurred. After that unexpected error, again google sign in starts to work with creating realm properly.

Logout code is as follows.

```
cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
        filesDir.deleteRecursively()

        AppUtilityFunctions.facebookSignout()
        AppUtilityFunctions.twitterSignout(this)

        //After logging out launch welcome page
        val intent = Intent(this, WelcomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME)
        startActivity(intent)


06-13 22:07:29.634 11246-11246/? D/REALM: jni: ThrowingException 5, , .
06-13 22:07:29.634 11246-11246/? D/REALM: Exception has been throw: File not found: .
06-13 22:07:29.634 11246-11246/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-13 22:07:29.634 11246-11246/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cccdb20)
06-13 22:07:29.634 11246-11272/? E/CrashlyticsCore: Tried to write a fatal exception while no session was open.
06-13 22:07:29.644 11246-11246/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.clinicloud.app.dev, PID: 11246
                                                   io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: File not found: .
                                                       at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions(Native Method)
                                                       at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<init>(SharedGroup.java:67)
                                                       at io.realm.internal.r.<init>(SharedGroupManager.java:47)
                                                       at io.realm.a.<init>(BaseRealm.java:76)
                                                       at io.realm.o.<init>(Realm.java:126)
```

Anyone has any clue on whats happening?

Comment: When executing the code above, are all instances of Realm closed? Realm does provide a method for deleting files related to a particular configuration: `Realm.deleteRealm()`

Comment: It sounds like you are somehow deleting the files after a login has occurred, but given the information above it is hard to tell why and where that is happening.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Hi Christian, I am not deleting anything. I have added the exception trace part of it. Does that give any clue.

Comment: @geisshirt Actually I used Realm.deleteRealm method only but did not remove all realm details after a fresh data load to realm, it was still holding old data thats why we made a decision to delete the realm file itself. Thanks.

Comment: `Realm.deleteRealm(config)` will return false if it could not delete the file because something else was holding a reference to it. You it returns false and you delete the file anyway, anything could happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this issue resolved by removing Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient) during google Sign in and put the signout code once I collected all the information from google related to user.